# Laravel 8 collection filter with raw DB query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a User model and a `users` table like so.

[image: users table]

Besides that I have a `verification_reminders` table.

[image: verification_reminders table]

`first_reminder` and `second_reminder` fields are nullable.

When a user signs up a record is inserted in the `users` table with a *null* `email_verified_at` field. When they verify their email the field is populated with a timestamp. If they take too long without verifying their email, a reminder is send out to them. As the reminder is being sent out for the first time a record is inserted in the `verification_reminders` table and the `first_reminder` is populated with a timestamp.

If they still do not verify a last final reminder is sent out and the `second_reminder` field populated with a timestamp.

I need to run a query to select users who have *null* `email_verified_at` in the `users` table.

Next I need to separate the users into two lists/collections:

1. Not reminded users who have *null* `email_verified_at` in the `users` table but no record of their `users_id` in the `verification_reminders` table.
2. First reminded users who have *null* `email_verified_at` in the `users` table and with a record of their `user_id` in the `verification_reminders` table with a populated `first_reminder` field but a *null* `second_reminder`

My attempt at this

```
    $users = User::whereNull('email_verified_at')->get();
    
    $users_not_reminded = collect($users)->filter(function($item){
            $reminded = DB::table('verification_reminders')->where('user_id', $item->id)->whereNull('first_reminder')->whereNull('second_reminder');
            
            if($reminded->isEmpty()){
                return $item;
            }
    
    });
```

I'm able to retrieve the `$users` but `$users_not_reminded` throws an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty()`

I've not even started on `$users_first_reminded` yet. I'm not sure how to proceed because this query is a bit too complicated for me. I'm hoping someone with experience could point out the cleaner way for me to achieve this.
Thank you. I'm using laravel 8 by the way.

Comment: Nothing complicated here. `isEmpty()` is not a valid method. Try `if (!$reminded->exists())` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not called first() or get() in db query

```
$reminded = DB::table('verification_reminders')
                 ->where('user_id', $item->id)
                 ->whereNull('first_reminder')
                ->whereNull('second_reminder');
```

so instead of above you should call first() or get()

```
  $reminded = DB::table('verification_reminders')
                     ->where('user_id', $item->id)
                     ->whereNull('first_reminder')
                    ->whereNull('second_reminder')
                    ->first();
```

I suggest you to Create model for `verification_reminders`  table then add relationship in user Model

```
public function verificationReminder(){

   return $this->hasOne(VerificationReminder::class);
}
```

then you can do

```
 $users = User::whereNull('email_verified_at')
                ->with('verificationReminder')
                ->whereHas('verificationReminder',function ($query){
                    $query->whereNull('first_reminder')
                         ->whereNull('second_reminder');
            }) ->get();
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, the best approach, by far, is to use the relation and let Laravel handle that way easier than creating a custom/raw query. Totally solvable woth relations. Best answer

Comment: That's the job!

Comment: I decided to go with this. It worked! Thanks.